# Multi-label ranking

Tags: ranking, labels

I have some input data which can belong to different outputs. I'm trying to determine if there's a pattern between the inputs and the output. I'm exploring using multi-label support vector machines in Accord and C#.

However, I'm not sure if it's exactly what I want. My data is in tuples for the input, and a single int for the output, however depending on the more occurances between similar inputs and the same output, I'd like a stronger relationship to be shown, and an output that reflects this.

It would seem support vector machines give either a yes/no answer as in, "yes these inputs corrolate to this class", and doesn't offer any ranking between other classes the inputs could belong to.

What options do I have to explore ranking between multiple labels?